# Getting String values to Adapter Class for view

Tags: android

I am currently having a Fragment class which gets String values from some other class.
I need to populate these values into a adapter class and set the view. The view class data for Student arrival time and Student name is obtained by the server -

```
Student arrival time     Student name      Present/Absent
    10:50                  John
    10:55                  Alex
    11:00                  Peter  
    11:07                  Mark
```

I am getting the String values in Fragment class for Present/Absent and I need to update in adapter class for view in Present/Absent column. 
Note that the arrival time is arranged in ascending order. So when the attendance is called out, the Present/Absent is recognised by voice recognition and 
populated in Present/Absent column.

I have 2 questions -

a) I need to create textviews for exactly same number of rows for columns Student name and Student arrival time

b) Even if I create textviews for exactly same number of rows, how do I change the textview value to Yes or No everytime because changing textview once will change for rest of them

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

[Here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) you can find a very good description how to use RecyclerView

Here is my example how it should look like:

## YourFragment

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private List<Student> studentList;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        studentList = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        adapter = new StudentsAdapter(studentList);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //This method fetch students list from server and insert them into studentList
        fetchStudentsList();
    }
}
```

## StudentsAdapter

```
public class StudentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Student> studentList;

    public StudentsAdapter(List<Student> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        holder.name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.student_name);
        holder.arrivalTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.student_arrival_time);
        holder.present = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.student_present);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Student student = studentList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(student.name);
        holder.arrivalTime.setText(student.arrivalTime);
        holder.present.setText(student.present ? R.string.yes : R.string.no);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return studentList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView name;
        public TextView arrivalTime;
        public TextView present;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

## Student.class

```
public class Student {
    public String arrivalTime;
    public String name;
    public boolean present;
}
```

To update some information in recyclerView, just change value in `Student` object and then call method `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

**See also:**

- [notifyItemChanged(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int))
- [notifyItemInserted(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int))
- [notifyItemRemoved(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRemoved(int))
- [notifyItemRangeChanged(int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeChanged(int,%20int))
- [notifyItemRangeInserted(int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeInserted(int,%20int))
- [notifyItemRangeRemoved(int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemRangeRemoved(int,%20int))

Comment: Is it possible that I could get the position of Abstract List View and based on the position, I update textview

Comment: Yes, you can use method `studentList.indexOf(studentA);` where `studentA` is some `Student` object. Method indexOf is using method `equals` to compare two objects, so you have to override method `equals` in `Student.class`, and compare two students, for example: by name